# How to input the given word line into different strings seperated by space?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, iostream

I am new to c++ and finding it difficult to use strings.User is inputting his full name i.e firstname and lastname seprated by space and **i want to store it in different strings while he inputs his name**

**Input**

ABC XYZ

**Code**

```
    string s1,s2;
    getline(cin,s1);
    
    getline(cin,s2);
    cout<<"Firstname :"<<s1<<endl;
    cout<<"Lastname :"<<s2<<endl;
```

**Output**

```
Firstname :ABC XYZ
Lastname :                //nothing is printed here , i want to sore the last name here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `std::getline` doesn't stop until it sees `\n`, you could provide your own delimeter instead:

```
string s1,s2;
getline(cin,s1, ' '); // stop at whitespace
getline(cin,s2); // stop at \n
```

---

Side note: In this small program it's fine, but as you get to bigger programs you'll want to refrain from using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Hm, you have a rep of 27k. So you are a very experienced C++ developer. But I guess that nobody would use ````std::getline```` in this way, just to read 2 strings. Nearly everybody would use ````std::cin >> s1 >> s2;````.  My guess is that you answered like this because OP used  ````std::getline```` . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny correct. Because mixing getline and cin leaves a mess I made sure to leave it as getline for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
 cin >> s1 >> s2;

 cout<<"Firstname :" << s1 <<endl;
 cout<<"Lastname :" << s2 <<endl;
```

or

```
    string s1,s2;
    getline(cin,s1);
    auto pos = s1.find(' ');
    s2 = s1.substr(pos);
    s1 = s1.substr(0, pos);
    cout<<"Firstname :" << s1 << endl;
    cout<<"Lastname :" << s2 << endl;
```

Comment: that was a typo mistake, now i have updated the question